# How to make only furture dates available with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, picker

I am using a datepicker off the web, jsDatePick.min.1.3.js. it works 100% but how do I limit dates to future only, so today and the next 5 days are not available to pick.

e.g: Today is 1/27/2015, the datePicker will only allow me to pick starting from 2/1/2015 onwards.

code for script is below and calls jsDatePick.min.1.3.js to process.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"inputField",
        limitToToday:false,
        dateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d",
    });
};
</script>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated. Please let me know if you require the js file.

Comment: http://javascriptcalendar.org/javascript-date-picker.php#intro

Comment: I would suggest using the jQuery date picker as it has a minDate attribute which will do exactly what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('.inputField').datepick({
        useMode: 2,
        limitToToday: false,
        dateFormat: "%Y-%m-%d",
        minDate: +6
    });
});
```